# how to add PDO mysql driver in Processmaker 4 PHP executor

Tags: processmaker

I need to connect to a mysql database from a processmaker script task. I tried using PDO but I get an error that cant find mysql driver.
I have tried modifying the executor configuration by adding:

- RUN apt-get install -y php7.2-mysql
- RUN apt-get install -y php-mysql
- RUN apt-get install -y php7-mysql

But none of the above work. During the build proces I get a message that can not find these packages. How should I go about adding the PDO mysql driver so that I can open connections to mysql databases in my PHP scripts?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to include the mysql support to the processmaker 4 PHP executor.
You can either modify the existing PHP executor or create a new php executor and add the following line to the dockerfile using the Processmaker interface

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

[image]

After adding this, save and rebuild the executor . Now when I run the code I no longer get the error message stating that the driver can not be found.